# How to Release Mouse Capture in Windows 2008 Server Hyper-V Virtual Machine?

Tags: hyper-v

I created a virtual machine under Hyper-V while connected via remote desktop - and discovered that the Hyper-V VM will not capture the mouse over terminal services.

Ok, the servers are across the hall, so no problem, I signed in at the console, and began installing the OS on the VM.

I'm in the process, and I can't remember how to release the mouse from the VM window, and I've googled for it, and can't find it.

Anyone want to spare me and tell me the keystrokes to release the mouse capture in my Hyper-V VM?

[I don't have the virtual extensions installed yet, as I am installing the guest OS]

Comment: Ok, I know this is a little numb, but I was desperate...the reason I needed to release the mouse was so that I could change the resolution on the machine - the windows were so large, I could not click on install options, etc...and I could not scroll the VM window, etc.

I finally retrieved the mouse having the session timeout while I was googling for the key sequence, and then logging back in again. ough.

Comment: Not "numb", nor anything. I was unable to quickly find it myself... Although I could simulate it by typing CTRL-ALT-DEL and esc'ing... Good question anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CTRL+ALT+LEFT ARROW
```

Comment: Intuitive stuff

Answer (score 0):

Control + Alt + LeftArrow